# Compilar sass con Gulp - Problema con la compilación

Tags: css, gulp, sass

### Problema en la compilación

mis archivos sass los tengo en "_lab/_scss/main.scss", dentro de "_scss" hay una carpeta "_include-scss" donde tengo los otros archivos .scss que los import desde "main.scss"; Pero mi problema es que cuando los compilo con gulp no se añaden los archivos @import en el archivo final main.css que lo tengo ruteado en la raíz del proyecto "css/main.css"

[image: Carpeta Raíz]

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
 font:{
  family: 'Raleway', 'Sans Serif';
  size: 14px;
  weight: 400;
 }
 body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
}


@import '_include-scss/_Style-Generales';
@import '_include-scss/_fonts';
@import '_include-scss/_botones';
@import '_include-scss/_header';
@import '_include-scss/_footer';
```

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
 sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('sass2css', function(){
 gulp.src('_lab/_scss/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Comment: Puedes pegar el contenido de main.scss en la pregunta?

Comment: listo esa es mi contenido main.scss

Comment: @MichaelCardoza Yo traté de reproducir tu problema con los datos que pones y me funciona a la perfección. Cree unos ficheros exactamente como los describes con algunas clases de ejemplo y los `@imports` se agregan como es de esperarse. Quizas hay algo en los ficheros que estás intentando agregar que está causando algun problema o te sale algun error en la consola?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo hago es importar todos mis partial dentro del `main.scss`, y pienso que lo hiciste bien.

Pero en tu archivo `gulpfile.js` solo tienes que llamar el `main.scss`, ya que los `@imports` los trabajará `Sass`; siendo está la corrección.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
 sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('sass2css', function(){
 gulp.src('_lab/_scss/main.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

He reproducido todo y me ha funcionado como ya lo tiene, pero pienso que por algún tema de versión podría quitar el _ de los import, ejemplo:

```css
@import '_include-scss/Style-Generales';
@import '_include-scss/fonts';
@import '_include-scss/botones';
@import '_include-scss/header';
@import '_include-scss/footer';
```